# CreateObject fails with error "CreateObject function was not declared"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012, I get the error "CreateObject function was not declared" in this line:

```
        _cMouseIndicator = CreateObject("twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator")
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here?
I thought that CreateObject was a part of one of the standard libraries.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this import:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction
```

then CreateObject should work.

CreateObject is a leftover from the classic Visual Basic like VB6, ASP, VBA and VBScript.

You can also achieve the same late-binding with this snippet:

```
Dim _cMouseIndicator As Object

Dim t As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("twsMouseIndicator.clsMouseIndicator", True)
_cMouseIndicator = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
```

But it would be painful to invoke methods on this object with InvokeMember calls.

I'd advise you to add the library you want as a *reference*. Visual Studio should handle the ActiveX COM imports with Interop and you can use your library with the **new** keyword.

Comment: In VB, for either option (CreateObject or Activator.CreateInstance) you need to have Option Strict Off.  In C#, the 'dynamic' keyword gives you slack on the relevant object, but without tossing the rest of the code in Option Strict Off coding horror land.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas dynamic is very convenient but if you use InvokeMember, CreateInstance should work even with Option Strict **On** although it causes my eyes to _bleed_. A working VB.NET example for the type "SAPI.SpVoice" would be: `SAPI.GetType().InvokeMember("Speak", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, SAPI, New Object() {"Hello world!", 0})`

Comment: Right - I overlooked that.  Totally agree on the bleeding eyes.

Comment: @FurkanOmay Thanks for the advice about adding the library. Unfortunately I can not do this because then VS does not use my class as out-of-proc anymore. I am only able to run my class with a different ProcessID, if I use CreateObject.

Comment: But I think the Activator approach also works great. Thank you very much!!